# Flask template executes HTML onclick function on page load

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

My template renders multiple cards to page and I want each card to have "Add to favorites" button to save cards information to DB as object. The problem is when I reload page it executes function for all items and doesn't respond to click at all.

cards.html
https://codepen.io/bordax/pen/YzWWQrb

app.py

```
def add_to_favorites(item):
    print(item['name'])

@app.route("/favorites")
def favorites():
    # Array of objects
    data = info_filter(food_data)

    return render_template("cards.html", data=data, add=add_to_favorites)
```

Comment: Are you expecting that doing `onclick="{{ add(item) }}"` will cause `add(item)` to be executed on click?  That's not how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `{{ stuff }}` in your template, `stuff` will be executed by Flask as part of building the page.  Filling in the template by evaluating `{{ }}` blocks happens on the server side before the browser ever sees the page.  Contrariwise, by the time the user is clicking on something on the web page, Flask is out of the picture and knows nothing about such clicks, unless the web page explicitly does something to notify the server.

Sadly, if you want to respond to browser events like clicks, you'll have to write JavaScript code, and have that code communicate with your Flask backend (e.g. by sending HTTP requests).

Comment: This explains why this function is executed on page load. Any suggestions how make Javascript communicate Flask backend?

Comment: That's too broad a question to answer here.  You can find lots of information by googling.